# Kubernetes save JSON logs to file with escaped quotes. Why?

Tags: json, logging, docker, kubernetes, fluentd

I'm using Fluentd with Elasticsearch for logs from Kubernetes but I noticed that some JSON logs cannot be correctly indexed because JSON is stored as string.

Logs from kubectl logs  look like:

```
{"timestamp":"2016-11-03T15:48:12.007Z","level":"INFO","thread":"cromwell-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4","logger":"akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger","message":"Slf4jLogger started","context":"default"}
```

But logs saved in file in /var/log/containers/... have escaped quotes and makes them string instead of JSON which spoil indexing:

```
{"log":"{\"timestamp\":\"2016-11-03T15:45:07.976Z\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"thread\":\"cromwell-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4\",\"logger\":\"akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger\",\"message\":\"Slf4jLogger started\",\"context\":\"default\"}\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2016-11-03T15:45:07.995443479Z"}
```

I'm trying to get logs looking like:

```
{
    "log": {
        "timestamp": "2016-11-03T15:45:07.976Z",
        "level": "INFO",
        "thread": "cromwell-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4",
        "logger": "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger",
        "message": "Slf4jLogger started",
        "context": "default"
    },
    "stream": "stdout",
    "time": "2016-11-03T15: 45: 07.995443479Z"
}
```

Can you suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, if someone has solved it would help a lot.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I, too, also, am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, however I'm using `fluent-bit`, the "C" version of `fluentd` (Ruby). Since this is an older issue, I'm answering for the benefit of others who find this.

In `fluent-bit` v0.13, they addressed this issue. You can now specify the parser to use through annotations. The parser can be configured to decode the log as json.

- [fluent-bit issue detailing problem](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/615)
- [blog post about annotations for specifying the parser](https://www.linux.com/blog/event/kubecon/2018/4/fluent-bit-flexible-logging-kubernetes)
- [json parser documentation](https://fluentbit.io/documentation/0.14/parser/json.html) - The docker container's logs come out as json. However, your logs are *also* json. So an [additional decoder](https://fluentbit.io/documentation/0.14/parser/decoder.html) is needed.

The final parser with decoder looks like this:

```
[PARSER]
    Name        embedded-json
    Format      json
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
    Time_Keep   On
    # Command      |  Decoder         | Field | Optional Action
    # =============|==================|=======|=========
    Decode_Field_As   escaped           log     do_next
    Decode_Field_As   json              log
```